# SQLDelight batch insert list

Tags: sqldelight

I'm having a problem inserting many rows with SQLDelight. I'm not sure if the query is deadlocked, or just taking many minutes. I'm inserting about 10k rows in two different tables.

Both have a `.sq` file like:

```sql
save:
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TableA VALUES ?;
```

my insert:

```kotlin
val tableAQueries = database.tableAQueries
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    tableAQueries.transaction {
        rows.forEach { tableAQueries.save(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try inserting in batches to see how long it will take approximately.

Comment: I gave up after 10 minutes. So it's something longer than that unless i have some deadlock. Doing the same thing with Room took a few seconds.

Comment: I mean split it in 10 or 100 transactions, to see how long one of them takes. Maybe even start with checking out that a single request finishes fine.

Comment: Well, I feel pretty silly. There's some deadlock, Thanks for the advice. Seems really obvious in hindsight, but my mind was somewhere else. I'll report back when I have some a better idea of how long the insert is actually taking.

Comment: OK, so that snippet I have posted is actually quite fast. I don't have any hard numbers, but it's comparable to Room. The real problem was some deadlock. Don't run a query on another thread in a mapper.

Comment: can you please add what you have done after this? so I can understand and solve my problem too

Comment: My problem was that I had another sql query in a mapper. The actual insert as written here worked fine.